# How to extract and save PDF layers In IText

Tags: pdf, itext, layer

I have a multi OCG layer PDF and I need to extract the content of each layer and save them as separated PDFs.I have seen various resources however I am not sure if IText is providing any tools/API to do such thing.

Adobe Acrobat reader X has got a feature that you can observe / modify layers as Containers.I need to know if IText can give us such control over the OCG layers  or not.

thanks for the responses

Comment: There's an `OCGRemover` in the itext-xtra package. Is that what you're looking for? It's not entirerly clear from your question.

Comment: Basically , I need to extract a OCG(Layer) and copy the content in a separate page or another PDF. This process should support transferring all dependant Images, resources, fonts paths and etc... XFinium has provided such tool in the api called "ExtractPageOptionContentGroup" however there is some issues on the behaviour of that method.

Comment: The `OCGRemover` does the opposite: it removes a layer instead of extracting it. It's only a matter of adapting the `OCGRemover` class to make it behave the way you want.

Comment: I have managed to achieve your proposed idea however apparently Itext.Xtra has some bugs as it is not able to remove some elements in one layer. for instance if we have 10 path and an image, it will remove 4 path and image including the layer(OCG) data.
I have tried to download the Opensource code from Github however Can not figure out why these paths are missing.. this would need in-depth knowledge on Acrobat PDF spec which I dont have it...